# Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web error in Sitecore Dynamic CRM Connector

Tags: xconnect, dynamics-crm-module, crm

I have installed and configured Connector for `Microsoft Dynamics 2.1.0`.
I am getting below error when click **Run Troubleshooter** on `xconnect` Client Endpoint.

> Could not load type 'Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.IHttpClientHandlerModifier' from assembly 'Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I have `Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.dll` in bin folder. Can someone please suggest possible cause.

FYI: Its clean instance of Sitecore 9.02

Comment: It could be the wrong version of Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web in your bin folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.IHttpClientHandlerModifier doesn`t exist in Sitecore 9.0.2 (only in Sitecore 9.1).

As I know Microsoft Dynamics 2.1.0 requires Sitecore 9.1 version. You can check sitecore modules compability here https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/541788.